# Spring Test transaction not rolling back

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-test

Using the spring testing framework, my transactions do not roll back and I have absolutely no idea why. I've spent a good few days trying to find answers on SO but to no avail so I decided to post.

Testfile

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContextTest.xml")
@Transactional
public class joinTest {

@Autowired
private DAO AccountDAO;//My DAO is annotated with @Repository


@Before
public void beforeMethod()
{
    //log4j append code
}

@Test
public void saveMethod()
 {
    Account acct = new Account();
    acct.setUsername("USER");
    SmokeEvent evt = new SmokeEvent();
    evt.setDateSmoked(new DateTime());
    evt.setAccount(acct);
    AccountDAO.addSmokeEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abstinence.Logic"/>
<context:annotation-config/>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://82.165.173.127/testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="SA"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abstinence.Logic"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key ="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="hibernateDAOOperation" expression="execution(* com.abstinence.Logic.AccountDAO.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="hibernateDAOOperation"/>
</aop:config>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I have checked the logs from log4j. The unusual thing is there is no mention of a rollback anywhere. There is a mention of the logs creating a session and inserting the data into the database but nothing about a rollback.

Someone please help me

Comment: Try to add transactionManager http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html

Comment: We need more information: What version of Spring are you using? Which `@Transactional` annotation is that (Spring's)? What is the log output when the logger for `org.springframework.test.context` is set to `DEBUG`? What does your DAO do? Does it invoke `getCurrentSession()` (correct) or `openSession()` (wrong) on the `SessionFactory`?

Comment: You are an extremely bright man for noticing that I wasn't using Spring's @Transactional but rather the J2EE's. Changed it to spring's and the transaction successfully rolled back. I'm quite a careless developer. Thank you so much for your comment. I'm happy to send you some bitcoins for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following annotation to your test class `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)` should fix your issue.

Comment: from Spring5 @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true) is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the `AccountDAO` is annotated with the `@Repository` annotation. Have you also annotated the DAO with `@Transactional`? Without it, no transaction will be created when the `addSmokeEvent()` method is executed in the test. Consequently, the event will be added to your DAO, but the transaction manager cannot rollback the operation.